# Problem of Harmonic function.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

If H is a harmonic function on an unit disk; And $H=0$ on $R_1\cup R_2$, here $R_1, R_2$ are radius of $D(0,1)$. The angle between $R_1$ and $ R_2$ is $r\pi$; here $r\in (0,1]$. If $r$ is an irrational number then is $H$ identically zero on $D(0,1)$?

---

> I think if $r$ is irrational then $H\equiv0$ on unit disk $D$; and
>   following lemma can help us to prove it.

**Lemma**:
If $a,b$ are two semilines starting at the same point $O$ there exists $u \not\equiv 0$ is a harmonic function vanishing on $a,b$ if and only if there exists $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that the angle between a and b is $r\pi.$

*Proof of the Lemma:* Using the following property of harmonic function we can prove this lemma.

1. A harmonic function vanishing on an open set is identically zero.
2. (Schwarz Reflection Principle) If a harmonic function is defined in a neighborhood of a line segment contained in one of the halfplanes determined by that segment and it is continued to zero on that segment, then it can be extended harmonically to the symmetric region by the given line segment.

Comment: Are you asking about how to prove the lemma in order to complete the proof, or are you asking about how to apply the lemma (taking for granted that the lemma is true) to this particular question?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom , I have the proof of this lemma. I wonder how to apply it to prove above statement.

Comment: This may seem like a strange point to be tripped up on, but I'm not sure what you mean by "semi-line".  Is this distinct from a line-segment?  If it is not, then we could certainly apply the lemma as follows: note that $R_1$ and $R_2$ are two semilines starting from the same point such that the angle between them is not a rational multiple of $\pi$. By our lemma, no non-zero harmonic function vanishes on $R_1 \cup R_2$.  We conclude that $H$ must be identically zero.

Comment: A semi-straight line is a line which has a boundary (or vetex) on one side and is infinite on the other side.

Comment: Why can't we apply above lemma if those $R_1,R_2$ are not semi-lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a semiline need only exist within the domain of the function (I am unsure of the definition), we have the following proof:

Note that $R_1$ and $R_2$ are two semilines starting from the same point such that the angle between them is not a rational multiple of $\pi$, and that $H$ is harmonic on the unit disk, which is a neighborhood of these two segments. By our lemma, no non-zero harmonic function vanishes on $R_1 \cup R_2$.  We conclude that $H$ must be identically zero.

Comment: I got your proof. Thank you Omnomnomnom.

Answer (score 0):

The Maximum and Minimum Principle of Harmonic functions imply that the answer of your question is positive.

Comment: How come? Please explain.

Comment: A harmonic function could never attain its Maximum and Minimum in the domain which it defined in. Then make a proof by contradiction.